# Filter posts by current date ( WP Post Carousel )

Tags: query-posts, date

So i managed to filter the posts with this snippet :

```
<?php 
echo " works";


$current_day = date('j');
$current_month = date('M');
query_posts('day='.$current_day.'&month='.$current_month);
if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();



    endwhile;
endif;

?>
```

The thing is that this plugin uses some other way to query the posts , exactly :

```
 require_once ( "includes/wp-posts-carousel-popular-posts-query.class.php" );
            $loop = new WP_Posts_Carousel_Popular_Posts_Query( apply_filters('wpc_query', $query_args, array(
                'params' => $params,
            ) ) );
        } else {
            $loop = new WP_Query( apply_filters('wpc_query', $query_args, array( 
                'params' => $params,
            ) ) );
        }
```

wp-posts-carousel-popular-posts-query.class.php :

```
<?php
/*
Author: Marcin Gierada
Author URI: http://www.teastudio.pl/
Author Email: m.gierada@teastudio.pl
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

/*
 * class to get populat posts from Wordpress Popular Posts plugin
 */
class WP_Posts_Carousel_Popular_Posts_Query extends WP_Query {
    private $args;

    function __construct($args) {
        $this->args = $args;

        add_filter( 'posts_fields', array( $this, 'posts_fields') );
        add_filter( 'posts_orderby', array( $this, 'posts_orderby' ) );

        parent::__construct($args);

        remove_filter( 'posts_fields', array( $this, 'posts_fields' ) );
        remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', array( $this, 'posts_orderby' ) );
    }

    function posts_fields($sql) {
        global $wpdb;
        return $sql . ", (SELECT SUM(". $wpdb->prefix . "popularpostsdata.pageviews) FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "popularpostsdata WHERE postid=" . $wpdb->posts . ".ID AND last_viewed > DATE_SUB('" . current_time('mysql') . "', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS views";
    }

    function posts_orderby($sql) {
        return "views " . $this->args['order'];
    }
}
?>
```

Can someone help me to convert my snippet and merge its function with the plugins functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WP_Query` to query posts from Date A to Date B, here are all Date Parameters for the `WP_Query` object :

```
//////Date Parameters - Show posts associated with a certain time and date period.
    //http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters
    'year' => 2014,                         //(int) - 4 digit year (e.g. 2011).
    'monthnum' => 4,                        //(int) - Month number (from 1 to 12).
    'w' =>  25,                             //(int) - Week of the year (from 0 to 53). Uses the MySQL WEEK command. The mode is dependenon the "start_of_week" option.
    'day' => 17,                            //(int) - Day of the month (from 1 to 31).
    'hour' => 13,                           //(int) - Hour (from 0 to 23).
    'minute' => 19,                         //(int) - Minute (from 0 to 60).
    'second' => 30,                         //(int) - Second (0 to 60).
    'm' => 201404,                          //(int) - YearMonth (For e.g.: 201307).
    'date_query' => array(                  //(array) - Date parameters (available with Version 3.7).
                                              //these are super powerful. check out the codex for more comprehensive code examples http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters
      array(
        'year' => 2014,                     //(int) - 4 digit year (e.g. 2011).
        'month' => 4                        //(int) - Month number (from 1 to 12).
        'week' => 31                        //(int) - Week of the year (from 0 to 53).
        'day' => 5                          //(int) - Day of the month (from 1 to 31).
        'hour' => 2                         //(int) - Hour (from 0 to 23).
        'minute' => 3                       //(int) - Minute (from 0 to 59).
        'second' => 36                      //(int) - Second (0 to 59).
        'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013', //(string/array) - Date to retrieve posts after. Accepts strtotime()-compatible string, or array of 'year', 'month', 'day'
        'before'    => array(               //(string/array) - Date to retrieve posts after. Accepts strtotime()-compatible string, or array of 'year', 'month', 'day'
          'year'  => 2013,                  //(string) Accepts any four-digit year. Default is empty.
          'month' => 2,                     //(string) The month of the year. Accepts numbers 1-12. Default: 12.
          'day'   => 28,                    //(string) The day of the month. Accepts numbers 1-31. Default: last day of month.
        ),
        'inclusive' => true,                //(boolean) - For after/before, whether exact value should be matched or not'.
        'compare' =>  '=',                  //(string) - Possible values are '=', '!=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN', 'EXISTS' (only in WP >= 3.5), and 'NOT EXISTS' (also only in WP >= 3.5). Default value is '='
        'column' => 'post_date',            //(string) - Column to query against. Default: 'post_date'.
        'relation' => 'AND',                //(string) - OR or AND, how the sub-arrays should be compared. Default: AND.
      ),
    ),
```

Source : https://gist.github.com/luetkemj/2023628

Comment: Also you can get the current timestamp by simply putting `time()` in a variable.